# SCTP kernel extension for Mavericks?

Tags: macos, python, kernel-extensions

I am about to do some development with SCTP using Python[1]. But this requires some kind of  3rd party kernel extensions to Mac OS X. The only link I can find about the kernel extension is completely out of date[2].

Any ideas on how to get the SCTP support into Mavericks?

[1] https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysctp

[2] http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/sctp-nke.html

Answer (score 1):

The SCTP reference implementation has an NKE version for Mavericks.

The repository is at http://code.google.com/p/sctp-refimpl/

A pre-built version can be found at https://nplab.fh-muenster.de/groups/wiki/wiki/bf935/SCTP_on_Mavericks.html